# Class stops working when defined as global

Tags: c++, class, global, local, definition

I am writing a program that uses camera data from the PSEye camera using the Code Laboratories drivers (http://www.codelaboratories.com/products/eye). So i created a header file called PSEyeGetter.h to directly interface with the drivers. When i use this class as a local variable in a function like this (note i am using OpenCV to display the image):

```
    void Test2()
    {
        cvNamedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        PSEyeGetter Get = PSEyeGetter(CLEYE_MONO_PROCESSED, CLEYE_VGA, 30);

        IplImage* img_cam =  cvCreateImage(cvSize(Get.W, Get.H), 8, Get.Size);

        while (1)
        {
            if (Get.GetFrame())
            {
                int Length = Get.W * Get.H * Get.Size;
                for (int cnt = 0; cnt < Length; cnt++)
                {
                    img_cam->imageData[cnt] = Get.CurrentColours[cnt];
                }
            }
            cvShowImage("Image", img_cam);

            if (cvWaitKey(10) == 27) break;
        }

        cvReleaseImage(&img_cam);
        cvDestroyAllWindows();
    }
```

I have no problems, the image displays perfectly. But when i try to define the PSEyeGetter a global variable like this:

```
    PSEyeGetter Cam;
    IplImage* img_cam;

    void OpenCam()
    {
        Cam = PSEyeGetter(CLEYE_MONO_PROCESSED, CLEYE_VGA, 30);
        img_cam =  cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), 8, 1);
        cvNamedWindow("Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    }

    void GetImage()
    {
        while (1)
        {
           if (Cam.GetFrame())
           {
               int Length = Cam.W * Cam.H * Cam.Size;
               for (int cnt = 0; cnt < Length; cnt++)
               {
                   Image->imageData[cnt] = Cam.CurrentColours[cnt];
               }

               cvShowImage("Image", img_cam);

               if (cvWaitKey(10) == 27) break;
           }
        }

        cvReleaseImage(&img_cam);
        cvDestroyAllWindows();
    }
```

It suddenly stops getting the image properly. It links to the camera and gets an image but the image is just blue. Any ideas why this might be?

Other bits of useful info
`CurrentColours = (PBYTE)malloc(W * H* Size * sizeof(byte));` where PBYTE is defined as (byte*). It is defined when creating the PSEyeGetter, and only released when the class is destroyed.

I need to define it as global as this is part of a much larger program that needs to operate on multiple threads, so i need to be able to access the camera from multiple places.

Thank you for any help. :)

Edit: Constructor for PSEyeGetter

```
    PSEyeGetter::PSEyeGetter(CLEyeCameraColorMode ColourMode, CLEyeCameraResolution Resolution, float FrameRate)
    {
        IsReady = false;
        Mode = ColourMode;
        Res = Resolution;
        Rate = FrameRate;
        switch(Mode)
        {
        case CLEYE_MONO_PROCESSED:
            Size = 1;
            break;
        case CLEYE_COLOR_PROCESSED:
            Size = 4;
            break;
        case CLEYE_MONO_RAW:
            Size = 1;
            break;
        case CLEYE_COLOR_RAW:
            Size = 4;
            break;
        case CLEYE_BAYER_RAW:
            Size = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (!FindCam()) return;
        CurrentColours = (PBYTE)malloc(W * H* Size * sizeof(byte));
    }

    bool PSEyeGetter::FindCam()
    {
        if (IsReady)
        {
            CLEyeCameraStop(Cam);
            CLEyeDestroyCamera(Cam);
            IsReady = false;
        }

        if (CLEyeGetCameraCount() == 1)
        {
            guid = CLEyeGetCameraUUID(0);
            Cam = CLEyeCreateCamera(guid, Mode, Res, Rate);
            CLEyeCameraGetFrameDimensions(Cam, W, H);
            IsReady = true;
            CLEyeCameraStart(Cam);
            CLEyeCameraLED(Cam, true);
        }
        else
        {
            IsReady = false;
        }

        return IsReady;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about OpenCV, but your call to `cvCreateImage` is very different in the second code.

Comment: oh... yer that makes no difference the size of the image is 640x480 with a depth of 1 (since I'm using b&W images). Basically its less dynamic, but in this case it doesn't matter

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `OpenCam()` before you call `GetImage()`? Also, you are calling `cvNamedWindow()` in a different order in the examples, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes i am calling them in that order, and no the order of `cvNamedWindow()` doesn't affect it.

Comment: Can you show the constructor for your `PSEyeGetter`?  That's now being called before `main()`, and may be counting on other data that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Don't think so, but i posted it up. Anything that seems undefined is within the header file

Comment: It's possible that the CL Eye library depends on some static objects to be set up and silently fails if they aren't, but since the documentation isn't openly accessible it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @molbdnilo that's possible, but wouldn't that affect both situations? or does defining as global mean something different from defining as local?

Comment: @Tails270 Yes, the relative initialisation order of globals (both static and non-static) in different "compilation units" is unspecified.